# Auto Router - Routes that are not home route doesn't work when I host the web app

Tags: flutter, auto-route

I have built a web app using flutter, and I used auto router package to handle the routes. The app was working good on local host,but when I hosted it on the internet all the routes doesn't work except the home route. I don't what is actually the problem.

to explain the problem:

when I use localhost:
localhost:61400/: It returns the home route
localhost:61400/register: It returns the register route

But when I hosted it:
domain.site/ : It returns the home route
domain.site/register: It returns 404

"Flutter doctor -v " output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3riZm.png)

I used Auto router package

run command :
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release